# Container-bound script deployed as Web App returns 404 (not found)

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a Spreadsheet-bound script with a single function:

```
function doGet() {
  Logger.log("test");
}
```

Then I deploy with: Execute as me, and Access - anyone, even anonymous.

However, going to published site fails with an error "Sorry, unable to open the file at this time." (or if accessed via curl - returns 404).

**Exactly** the same procedure works in standalone scripts. Is there a limitation or a gotcha about container-bound scripts?

Comment: That happened to me recently and I resolved the issue by terminating and restarting the browser session.  Perhaps that will work for you.  Don't know why that worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a bug. The published endpoint URL returned from a container-bound script has a different structure than a endpoint URL for a standalone script.

Container-bound:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/u/1/s/<script-id>/exec
```

Standalone:

```
https://script.google.com/a/<google-apps-domain>/macros/s/<script-id>/exec
```

The solution was to use the url structure of a standalone script and replace `<script-id>` for the script that I need. This seems to have worked.

Comment: It looks that removing `u/1/` fixs the problem. I updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47026641/1595451)

Answer (score 1):

## Workaround

Container bound script URL have the following form:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/u/1/s/<script-id>/exec
```

Remove the `u/1/` part:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/<script-id>/exec
```

### Reference

- [Comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65671881#comment2) to [Apps Script Wrong Web App URL From Script Editor (returns status code 404, with extra /u/1 in URL)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65671881)

## Explanation

At this time are two issues that looks to be related

- [Apps Script Wrong Web App URL From Script Editor (returns status code 404, with extra /u/1 in URL)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65671881)
- [Container-bound script is not reachable (404) when deployed as Web App](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68670522)

It's worth to note, from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web,

> Requirements for web apps
>
> As script can be published as a web app if it meets these requirements:
>
> - It contains a doGet(e) or doPost(e) function.
> - The function returns an HTML service HtmlOutput object or a Content service 
>     TextOutput object.

As I understand the above, there is a problem with your script: it fails to return an object. Anyway, it should return

> The script completed but did not return anything.

For a one line web app, try something like the following:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('Hello world!');
}
```

Regarding an explanation about why your code "works" on a stand-alone script but returns an error on a bounded-script, perhaps it's a glitch and it will be solved "by itself" soon. If it doesn't, checkout the Issue Tracker (follow the link on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/)

Comment: Fair point - I was actually returning a `TextOutput`, but for some reason changed it in the question itself. The issue still remains, however.

Comment: @NewDev: Did you already tried to reproduce the problem by creating a new script from scratch ?

Comment: yes - starting from scratch: a new spreadsheet, new apps script with a single `doGet` function, deployed