# Unable to execute deployed sheets script web app. Getting 404

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-deployment

I have simple script created as macro within google sheets:

`function doGet() {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('I just successfully handled your GET request.');
}`

It works when I am trying testing implementation. After deployment I am getting 404 return code.
My generated url is https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXX/exec

I am using just one google account (already know a similar bug with multiple accounts).
I have a simple free google account - no gsuite or domain.
I tried to log out and log in again.
I tried to change permission settings for everyone, just for me - all combinations.

Are there some extra permissions settings or I there some limitations for free accounts?

Comment: You can refer to this as you have similar case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47026444/container-bound-script-deployed-as-web-app-returns-404-not-found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Container-bound script deployed as Web App returns 404 (not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47026444/container-bound-script-deployed-as-web-app-returns-404-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. It was my fault.

Every time when I wanted to deploy changes I just re-deployed the original one. So I realized that I have to create new implementations every time.

So I hope this helps somebody who is new in this domain as I am.